# Need help understanding Docker Service scale Port Binding

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I understand that in docker, multiple containers cannot bind to the same port on the host machine.

If that is correct, then I would like to have an understanding of how `docker service scale SERVICE=num` (assuming we running this on the Manager machine) is able to create replicated containers that are all binding to the **same port on host machine**.

I'm confused and need help on how docker manages to make that happen.

Thanks for any support or suggested links that would help me with answers.

Comment: I guess the replicated containers have different IPs. Am I right?

Comment: Yes they do. Docker automatically assigns unique IPs to them

Comment: Do the replicated containers bind the ports to the host machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer to my question after a few research. I hope this helps someone.

Quoted Answer from user called thaJeztha at https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/26817

"This is expected; port publishing for services works different than for "regular" containers;

When creating a service, ports of the containers backing the service are themselves not published directly, but go through the built-in load balancing for Swarm mode.

Inspecting individual containers, therefore doesn't show published ports, but inspecting the service will show the ports that are published;"